# basic python vlookup equivalent

Tags: python

I'm looking for the equivalent to the vlookup function in excel. I have a script where I read in a csv file.  I would like to be able to query an associated value from another column in the .csv. Script so far:

```
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.mlab as mlab
import glob

for files in glob.glob("*.csv"):
    print files

    r = mlab.csv2rec(files)
    r.cols = r.dtype.names

    depVar = r[r.cols[0]]
    indVar = r[r.cols[1]]
    print indVar
```

This will read in from .csv files in the same folder the script is in.  In the above example depVar is the first column in the .csv, and indVar is the second column. In my case, I know a value for indVar, and I want to return the associated value for depVar.  I'd like to add a command like:

```
depVar = r[r.cols[0]]
indVar = r[r.cols[1]]
print indVar
depVarAt5 = lookup value in depVar where indVar = 5 (I could sub in things for the 5 later)
```

In my case, all values in all fields are numbers and all of the values of indVar are unique.  I want to be able to define a new variable (depVarAt5 in last example) equal to the associated value.

Here's example .csv contents, name the file anything and place it in same folder as script. In this example, depVarAt5 should be set equal to 16.1309.

```
Temp,Depth
16.1309,5
16.1476,94.4007
16.2488,100.552
16.4232,106.573
16.4637,112.796
16.478,118.696
16.4961,124.925
16.5105,131.101
16.5462,137.325
16.7016,143.186
16.8575,149.101
16.9369,155.148
17.0462,161.187
```

Comment: An example input file and expected output listing would  be helpful.

Comment: And, just a note, not relevant to your question:  Your data is numeric and ordered... So I wonder if this is supposed to represent a continuous function.  In that case, you probably want some sort of interpolation, not just a lookup.  (Excel VLOOKUP does not do interpolation, but rather just finds the closest value.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this solves your problem quite directly:

```
import numpy
import glob

for f in glob.glob("*.csv"):
    print f

    r = numpy.recfromcsv(f)
    print numpy.interp(5, r.depth, r.temp)
```

I'm pretty sure numpy is a prerequisite for matplotlib.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what that `r` object is, but since it has a member called `cols`, I'm going to assume it also has a member called `rows` which contains the row data.

```
>>> r.rows
[[16.1309, 5], [16.1476, 94.4007], ...]
```

In that case, your pseudocode very nearly contains a valid generator expression/list comprehension.

```
depVarAt5 = lookup value in depVar where indVar = 5 (I could sub in things for the 5 later)
```

becomes

```
depVarAt5 = [row[0] for row in r.rows if row[1] == 5]
```

Or, more generally

```
depVarValue = [row[depVarColIndex] for row in r.rows if row[indVarColIndex] == searchValue]
```

so

```
def vlookup(rows, searchColumn, dataColumn, searchValue):
    return [row[dataColumn] for row in rows if row[searchColumn] == searchValue]
```

Throw a `[0]` on the end of that if you can guarantee there will be exactly one output per input.

There's also a `csv` module in the Python standard libary which you might prefer to work with. =)

Comment: There's no r.rows.  I edited the post a little after the original post where I defined r. I can't get your solution working as is, but thanks for trying

Answer (score 0):

For arbitrary orderings and exact matches you can use `indVar.index()` and index `depVar` with the returned index.

If `indVar` is ordered and (well, "or", sort of) you need closest match then you should look at using `bisect` on `indVar`.